# SAXParseException with AXIS Webservice Framework

Tags: xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, axis

We are working on webservice solution.
The webservice API provides us several calls using which we can retrieve the SOAP response from Client WebService implementaion.

The implementation is based on AXIS framework.

All API calls work well except in one we are facing SAXParseException when we get the response back.

When we try in SOAP UI we get valid response for this particular API . But when we try in Java project we get this SAXParseException. Both Java and SOAP UI projects have been created using same WSDL file

Please have a look at the stacktrace below and share your humble opinion what might have gone wrong here.

```
    XML received:
2013-05-14 12:12:20,536 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender - -----------------------------------------------
2013-05-14 12:12:20,536 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.SOAPPart - Enter: SOAPPart::getAsSOAPEnvelope()
2013-05-14 12:12:20,536 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(currForm)
2013-05-14 12:12:20,536 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.SOAPPart - current form is FORM_INPUTSTREAM
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The root element is required in a well-formed document.
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.SOAPPart - Enter: SOAPPart ctor(FORM_FAULT)
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setMsgForm)
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.SOAPPart - Setting current message form to: FORM_FAULT (currentMessage is now org.apache.axis.AxisFault)
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.SOAPPart - Exit: SOAPPart ctor()
2013-05-14 12:12:20,708 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(toAxisFault00)
2013-05-14 12:12:20,740 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.axis.enterprise - Mapping Exception to AxisFault
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The root element is required in a well-formed document.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The root element is required in a well-formed document.
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.reportError(XMLParser.java:1213)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.reportFatalXMLError(XMLDocumentScanner.java:570)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$XMLDeclDispatcher.endOfInput(XMLDocumentScanner.java:790)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.endOfInput(XMLDocumentScanner.java:418)
    at org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.sendEndOfInputNotifications(XMLValidator.java:712)
    at org.apache.xerces.readers.DefaultEntityHandler.changeReaders(DefaultEntityHandler.java:1031)
    at org.apache.xerces.readers.XMLEntityReader.changeReaders(XMLEntityReader.java:168)
    at org.apache.xerces.readers.AbstractCharReader.changeReaders(AbstractCharReader.java:150)
    at org.apache.xerces.readers.AbstractCharReader.lookingAtChar(AbstractCharReader.java:217)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$XMLDeclDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScanner.java:686)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.parseSome(XMLDocumentScanner.java:381)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1098)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you got no valid xml in response ... something like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node1>
 ... bla, bla
</node1>
<node2>
 ... bla, bla
</node2>
<node_x>
 ... bla, bla
</node_x>
```

instead ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node1>
  <node2>
   ... bla, bla
  </node2>
  <node_x>
    ... bla, bla
  </node_x>
</node1>
```

You should sniff the network traffic to see the content in raw format. I usually get this error if someone construct xml code by hand and not with well known tools.

Comment: yes even i think so. We are still with same error. When we try in SOAP UI we get valid response for this particular API . But when we try in Java we get this error. Both Java and SOAP UI projects have been created using same WSDL file